# Likelihood ratio test versus AIC for model comparison

Tags: aic, likelihood-ratio, model-comparison

When performing model comparison, why does the likelihood ratio test require two nested models while this is not required when using the AIC?

Comment: because one is based on assuming nested models, while the other is derived under different considerations?

Comment: Standard asymptotics for likelihood ratio tests are based on the idea of nested models; practically the smaller model is a special case of the larger model. On the other hand AIC is based on an information theoretical approach that is in a way structure agnostic. The book by Burnham
& Anderson "Model Selection and Multimodel Inference" gives a very good overview on the matter.